# LocalDB is not supported on this platform When using migrations

Tags: sql, .net, localdb

I am very new with .Net and I was just following the instructions given by Microsoft for my first project here : [Add a Model to Razor Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/model?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

Now when I run this command in the command line

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

I get the following error:
[image]

I decide to progress anyways and run the application. I put the appended url into my web browser and received this error :

[image]

Any clues on what can be done? I dont think there is an issue with the code because the project runs perfectly otherwise.

Comment: What does your connection string look like

Comment: What is your platform / Operating system?

Comment: MacOs Catilina 10.15.2